# How to call operator= from class 'X' into class 'Y' with its own operator= function?

Tags: c++, constructor, operator-overloading, deque

**Can someone help me figure out how to call an operator overloaded function from one class into another class when both classes have functions titled operator=?**

I have a class called "Deque" that represents a double ended queue. This double ended queue is made using linked nodes that I call "DequeNode". Each "DequeNode" has the private data members of a next and prev pointer as well as a variable to store a value/item. I have tested the deque.cpp and deque.h files with a driver I wrote and they are working as intended.

I want to make a class called LongInt, that presents an integer. A LongInt is supposed to represent an integer value that cannot be stored in an int variable. A LongInt has three private data members, a Deque object called digits, a bool, called negative, to determine if the value being stored in a LongInt is negative or positive, and a function to remove extra 0's at the front of the LongInt object.

I am having trouble writing the overloaded assignment operator (operator=) for the LongInt class (located in longint.cpp). The assignment operator for the LongInt class should take whatever is on the RHS of the '=' sign and make a copy of that to the current object/LHS of the '=' sign. To do this, I need to find a way to copy the Deque object of the RHS of the '=' to the LHS. To do this, in the operator= function in longint.cpp, I want to **use the operator= function from the deque.cpp** file to set the digits object of the item **on the LHS of the operator= function of longint.cpp**. **However, I am not sure how to do this and that is my main ask for help with. Can someone help me out with this?**

To maybe put this another way, inside the operator= function in longint.cpp, I want to use the "Deque(const Deque &rhs);" constructor from the Deque class to make a new Deque object. I want to pass in the Deque object from the LongInt object being passed into the operator= function in longint.cpp to the constructor from the Deque.cpp class.

Below is the code for the files: deque.h, deque.cpp, longint.h, and longint.cpp.

**deque.h:**

```
#ifndef DEQUE_H
#define DEQUE_H
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class Object>
class Deque {
 public:
  Deque();                                   // the constructor
  Deque(const Deque &rhs);                  // the copy constructor
  ~Deque();                                  // the destructor

  bool isEmpty() const;                      // checks if a deque is empty.
  int size() const;                          // retrieves # deque nodes
  const Object &getFront() const;            // retrieve the front node
  const Object &getBack() const;             // retrieve the tail node

  void clear();                              // clean up all deque entries.
  void addFront(const Object &obj);         // add a new node to the front
  void addBack(const Object &obj);          // add a new node to the tail
  Object removeFront();                      // remove the front node
  Object removeBack();                       // remove the tail node

  const Deque &operator=(const Deque &rhs); // assignment

 private:
  struct DequeNode {                          // a deque node
    Object item;
    DequeNode *next;
    DequeNode *prev;
  };
  DequeNode *front;
  DequeNode *back;
};

#include "deque.cpp"
#endif
```

**deque.cpp:**

```
template <class Object>
Deque<Object>::Deque() {                          // the constructor
  front = back = NULL;
}

template <class Object>
Deque<Object>::Deque(const Deque &rhs) {         // the copy constructor
  front = back = NULL;
  *this = rhs;
}

template <class Object>
Deque<Object>::~Deque() {                         // the destructor
  clear();
}

template <class Object>
bool Deque<Object>::isEmpty() const {             // check if a deque is empty
  return front == NULL;
}

template <class Object>
int Deque<Object>::size() const {                 // retrieves # deque nodes
  int i = 0;
  for ( DequeNode *ptr = front; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->next ) // traverse que
    ++i;

  return i;
}

template <class Object>
const Object &Deque<Object>::getFront() const {   // retrieve the front node
  if (isEmpty())
    throw "empty queue";
  return front->item;
}

template <class Object>
const Object &Deque<Object>::getBack() const {    // retrieve the tail node
  if (isEmpty())
    throw "empty queue";
  return back->item;
}

template <class Object>
void Deque<Object>::clear() {          // clean up all entries.
  while (!isEmpty())                 // dequeue till the queue gets empty.
    removeFront();
}
// add a new node to front
template <class Object>
void Deque<Object>::addFront(const Object &obj){

  DequeNode *new_node = new DequeNode;

  new_node->prev = NULL;
  new_node->next = front;
  new_node->item = obj;

//Checking for the edge case where we have no nodes
  if (front == NULL){  //If we have no nodes, both front and back get set to the only node.
    back = new_node;
    front = new_node;
  }
  else{ //Else, everything else is handled by this
    front->prev = new_node;
    front = new_node;
  }
}

// add a new node to tail
template <class Object>
void Deque<Object>::addBack(const Object &obj){

  DequeNode *new_node = new DequeNode;
  
  new_node->prev = back;
  new_node->next = NULL;
  new_node->item = obj;
  
//Checking for the edge case where we have no nodes
  if (back==NULL){ //If we have no nodes, both front and back get set to the only node.
    front = new_node;
    back = new_node;
  }
  else{ //Else, everything else is handled by this
    back->next = new_node;
    back = new_node;
  }
}

template <class Object>
Object Deque<Object>::removeFront(){  //remove the front node

  DequeNode *pos = front; //create a pointer to keep track of node to be deleted

  //Need to find a way to access the item being help at the location of front.
  Object removedItem = pos->item;

  if(front == back){ //Case for when there is only a single node left in the Queue.
    front = NULL;
    back = NULL;
  }
  else{ //All other cases should fall into this else statement
    front->next->prev = NULL;
    //front->next = NULL;
    front = front->next;
  }

  delete pos;

  return removedItem;
}

template <class Object>
Object Deque<Object>::removeBack(){   // remove the tail node

  DequeNode *pos = back; //create a pointer to keep track of node to be deleted

  //Need to find a way to access the item being help at the location of front.
  Object removedItem = pos->item;

  if(front==back){
    front = NULL;
    back = NULL;
  }
  else{
    back->prev->next = NULL;
    back = back->prev;
  }

  delete pos;
  return removedItem;
}

template <class Object>
const Deque<Object> &Deque<Object>::operator=(const Deque &rhs) { // assign
  if (this != &rhs) { // avoid self assignment
    clear();
    for (DequeNode *rptr = rhs.front; rptr != NULL; rptr = rptr->next)
      addBack(rptr->item);
  }
  return *this;
}
```

**longint.h:**

```
#ifndef LONGINT_H
#define LONGINT_H
#include <iostream>
#include "deque.h"

using namespace std;

class LongInt {
  friend istream &operator>>(istream &in, LongInt &rhs);
  friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, const LongInt &rhs);
 public:
  // Constructors
  LongInt(const string str); 
  LongInt(const LongInt &rhs);
  LongInt();

  // Destructor
  ~LongInt();

  // Arithmetic binary operators
  LongInt operator+(const LongInt &rhs) const;
  LongInt operator-(const LongInt &rhs) const;

  // assignment operators
  const LongInt &operator=(const LongInt &rhs);

  // Logical binary operators
  bool operator< (const LongInt & rhs) const;
  bool operator<=(const LongInt & rhs) const;
  bool operator> (const LongInt & rhs) const;
  bool operator>=(const LongInt & rhs) const;
  bool operator==(const LongInt & rhs) const;
  bool operator!=(const LongInt & rhs) const;

 private:
  Deque<char> digits;
  bool negative;
  void remove0s();
};

#endif
```

**longint.cpp:**

```
#include "longint.h"

//istream &operator>>(istream &in, LongInt &rhs){
  //return in;
//}

ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, const LongInt &rhs){
  //LongInt tmp = rhs;


  cout << "entering the operator<<" << endl;

  cout <<"get front in main: " << rhs.digits.getFront() << endl;
  cout << "get back in main: " << rhs.digits.getBack() << endl;

  return out;
}

//Constructors
//Here I want to go through the entire string and add all the values to the string in the correct order in the string.
LongInt::LongInt(const string str){
  cout << "constructor w/ str input" << endl;
  int i = 0;
  while (str[i]){
    digits.addBack(str[i]);
    i++;
  }
}

//LongInt::LongInt(const LongInt &rhs)

LongInt::LongInt(){
  cout << "constructor w/no parameters" << endl;
  digits.addBack('0');
  cout <<"getBack of default constructor: " << digits.getBack() << endl;
  cout << "size of current digits deque: " << digits.size() << endl;

  negative = false;
}

// Destructor
LongInt::~LongInt(){
  digits.clear();
}

// Arithmetic binary operators
//LongInt operator+(const LongInt &rhs) const;
//LongInt operator-(const LongInt &rhs) const;

// assignment operators
const LongInt & LongInt::operator=(const LongInt &rhs){

  this->negative = rhs.negative; //Set the new LongInt sign to the RHS sign.
  this->digits = Deque<char>(rhs.digits); //How do I call the deque classes operator= function?

  return *this;

}

// Logical binary operators
//bool operator< (const LongInt & rhs) const;
//bool operator<=(const LongInt & rhs) const;
//bool operator> (const LongInt & rhs) const;
//bool operator>=(const LongInt & rhs) const;
//bool operator==(const LongInt & rhs) const;
//bool operator!=(const LongInt & rhs) const;
```

Comment: `this->digits = rhs.digits` will call `Deque::operator=` because `this->digits` is a `Deque`.

Comment: Do you really need to show so much code to ask your question? Please see how to make a [mre]

Comment: @NathanPierson, thank you! That is what I was looking to do!

I still have another problem with my code, where when I call the assignment operator, I am getting the following error: 
`
undefined reference to `LongInt::LongInt(LongInt const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
`
And will now need to debug that. But thank you for the quick reply.